# How to mount file, passed inside command line in docker?

Tags: docker

I need a file be accessible to my docker image, which I have defined with

```
VOLUME /sdcard
```

in `Dockerfile`. Then I specified

```
--volume=$(pwd)/sdcard:/sdcard
```

in `docker run` command line. Now I need to have this file put into this directory.

Is it possible to do this by command line? I.e. specify `mydirectory/myfile` in docker run command line and have this file automatically mounted into some directory?

Comment: You have already done this?  You told docker to put it in /sdcard.  If you want it somewhere different change where you put it in the --volume clause

Comment: I want Docker to take single file from whenever I specify and put it into `/sdcard/somename.img`  for virtual machine; and I prefer not to expose "volume" syntax, just '.....some docker command... <filepath>

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "expose volume syntax".  You don't actually need `VOLUME` in your docker file.  `--volume` syntax creates a bind mount between your host machine and the container which is what you appear to be asking for.  This can be a directory or a single file.  The only thing you can't do with this is change the mounts after you created the container.